# retrieving the 'many' end of a Generic Foreign Key relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, tastypie

In Django, when I request a resource that has a many-to-many relationship, I end up getting *all* the items in child part of the relationship, even those not directly related to the parent.  It'll be easier if I show you with code (classes trimmed down to only show what's necessary):

#### Models

```
class Report(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), populate_from='name')
    wells = models.ManyToManyField(Well, null=True)
    uuid = UUIDField(editable=False, blank=True, version=4, unique=True)


class Well(models.Model):
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), populate_from='name')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Node(models.Model):
    @property
    def well(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("The 'well' field must be implemented")
    //irrelevant GFK omitted
    page_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True, related_name='page')
    page_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    page_content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('page_content_type', 
     'page_object_id')
```

#### Resources

```
class ReportResource(ModelResource):
    wells = fields.ManyToManyField(WellResource, 'wells', full=True)
    stock = fields.ForeignKey(TickerResource, 'stock', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Report.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'ticker_reports'

class WellResource(ModelResource):
    nodes = fields.ToManyField('wells.api.NodeResource', 'nodes', full=True)
    type = fields.ForeignKey(WellTypeResource, 'type', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Well.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'wells'

class NodeResource(ModelResource):
    order = fields.IntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKeyField({
                                                Content: UUIDOnlyContentResource
                                            }, 'content_object', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Node.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'nodes'
        filtering = {
            'ticker_report': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

A Ticker Report has many Wells, and these Wells are shared across all Ticker Reports.  What is different is that you can tie Nodes to Wells; for a given ticker report, the only nodes that should display are the ones that are related to that Ticker Report.

So, for a given ticker report and a set of wells, only the nodes that share that GenericForeignKey to that Ticker report should be shown.

Relationships:

`page_object_id`,`page_content_object`, `page_content_type` is a GenericForeignKey relationship to Report

Currently, all Nodes are shown (this is a bug).

In TastyPie, how do I tell it to only show the related objects and not all objects?

Here's a short python console that shows the problem more succicintly:

```
>>> r = Report.objects.get(id=1)                                                                                                        
>>> for well in r.wells.all():                                                                                                          
...     for node in well.nodes.all():                                                                                                   
...         print 'Node in Well {0} is {1}'.format(well, node)                                                                          
...                                                                                                                                     
Node in Well The Areas You Must Watch (the-areas-you-must-watch - Fancy List) is Apple Content #1:Apple (0)                             
Node in Well The Areas You Must Watch (the-areas-you-must-watch - Fancy List) is First Solar Content #1:first solar (0)                 
Node in Well Risks (risks - Headline and Lead) is Apple Content #2:Apple (0)                                                            
Node in Well Risks (risks - Headline and Lead) is First Solar Content #2:first solar (0)                                                
>>>
```

#### SQL Actual Output

```
SELECT node.id, node.uuid, node.order,node.content_type_id, node.object_id,
       node.page_content_type_id, node.page_object_id, node.well_id FROM node 
WHERE node.well_id = 1  
ORDER BY node.order ASC
```

(Modified to make it easier to read)

#### Expected SQL Output:

```
SELECT node.id, node.uuid, node.order,node.content_type_id, node.object_id,
       node.page_content_type_id, node.page_object_id, node.well_id FROM node 
WHERE node.well_id = 1  AND node.page_content_type_id = 99 /*Report Content TypeID */ AND node.page_content_object_id = 1 /*ReportID*/
ORDER BY node.order ASC
```

#### Expected output:

```
Node in Well The Areas You Must Watch is Apple Content #1
Node in Well Risks is Apple Content #2:Apple (0)
```

How can I filter out the child end of a many-to-many relationship with Django and TastyPie (though this problem is apparent without TastyPie as well, leaving me to believe it's a structural issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute the query

```
well.nodes.all()
```

this fetches *all* nodes that are related to `well` via the relationship you described in your model.

It sounds as though you want to limit the nodes returned to those that reference the `Report` object `r` via the `page_content_object` generic foreign key relation. Is that right? If it is, then you need to filter the nodes explicitly, like this:

```
r = Report.objects.get(id=1)
for well in r.wells.all():                                                                                                          
    for node in well.nodes.filter(page_object_id = r.id,
                                  page_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(r)):
        # ...
```

Update: I don't know anything about TastyPie and I have to say that I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but in Django, if there is a relation between wells and nodes, then you need to add it to your models. For example, if each `Node` belongs to exactly one `Well`, the natural thing to do would be to add a field to the `Node` model:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    # ...
    well = models.ForeignKey('Well')
```

and then if you want to find all nodes that belong to wells that belong to a particular `Report` object `r`, said nodes also referencing `r` via the generic foreign key relation, you'd issue the query:

```
 Node.objects.filter(well__report = r,
                     page_object_id = r.id,
                     page_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(r))
```

If you have to do this a lot, then a natural thing to do would be to add a method on the `Report` model.

Answer (score 1):

> A Ticker Report has many Wells, and these Wells are shared across all
>   Ticker Reports. What is different is that you can tie Nodes to Wells;
>   for a given ticker report, the only nodes that should display are the
>   ones that are related to that Ticker Report.
>
> In Django, when I request a resource that has a many-to-many
>   relationship, I end up getting all the items in child part of the
>   relationship, even those not directly related to the parent. It'll be
>   easier if I show you with code (classes trimmed down to only show
>   what's necessary):

If I understand correctly, the node can be related to report or wells (because you mentioned **related to that Ticke Report**).
And you are looking for the **node related to the report**, not the **nodes related to the wells of the report**. (because you are looking for node directly related to the parent(report?) )

If I am correctly, it is quite simple:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations

```
class Report(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), populate_from='name')
    wells = models.ManyToManyField(Well, null=True)
    uuid = UUIDField(editable=False, blank=True, version=4, unique=True)

    nodes = generic.GenericRelation(Node)


# usage
r = Report.objects.get(id=1)
nodes = r.nodes.all()
```